# R: case_when and filter combination resulting in undefined column select error

Tags: r, dplyr, undefined

I am having trouble using a combination of the `case_when` and `filter` functions in a loop from the `dplyr` package in R.

I have the following code (`data` is a dataframe that contains a column named `kind` of type double):

```
groupkind <- c('club', 'team', 'community')

for(k in groupkind) {
  data_groupkind <- case_when(
    k == 'club' ~ filter(data, kind %in% c(2,4)),
    k == 'team' ~ filter(data, kind %in% c(3,5,6,11)),
    k == 'community' ~ filter(data, kind == 0))
  )
}
```

Of course I am doing many other things in the loop, but this is the section of code that is problematic.

While running this piece of code, I get the following error straight from the first iteration: 
`Error in [.data.frame(value[[1]], rep(NA_integer_, m)) : undefined columns selected`.

The odd thing is that when I run `filter(data, kind %in% c(2,4))` outside the loop I don't get any error. And the `case_when` function works properly as well when I assign `data_groupkind` to anything else inside the loop.

So am I missing something here, or is it a bug from `dplyr`?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` is not designed to return dataframe/tibbles. Use `switch` or better simple `if`/`else`.

```
library(dplyr)

for(k in groupkind) {
  data_groupkind <- if(k == 'club') filter(data, kind %in% c(2,4)),
                    else if(k == 'team') filter(data, kind %in% c(3,5,6,11)),
                    else if(k == 'community') filter(data, kind == 0)
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, I guess I should have been more careful about reading doc. I ended up using the simple ifelse solution of course, but I was wondering wether case_when was behaving in a way it shouldn't. Anyway thanks for the clarification